Taillight and brake light problems
I have a 2007 trailblazer that I am have problems with. The taillights and brake lights aren't working right. I either have both brake lights working and no taillights or I have taillights but no brake light or 1 taillight and no brake light on one side and brake light and no taillight on the other. What would cause this problem
